# Changing bootstrap panel title with js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the panel title when a button is clicked.

I've tried to assign an id to the panel-title but it seems a wrong approach

```
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 id="something" class="panel-title">Engagement Indicators Average</h4>
                    </div>

                   document.getElementById('something').innerHTML = 'New title';
```

Comment: are you by any chance placing your javascript code inside your HMTL without `<script>` tag?

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById('btn_change').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('something').innerHTML = 'New title';
});
```

```html
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 id="something" class="panel-title">Engagement Indicators Average</h4>
</div>
<button id="btn_change">
Change my title
</button>
```

Use the snippet above as a guide. It works.